# How to apply css to the property of the tag?

Tags: css, reactjs, stylesheet, scss-lint

I am new to css and i would like to know if css can be applied to the properties of tag? 
For example in the below code i would like to see entry.count and "files" in blue color.

code

```
  render() {

    return(
      <div className="AppL" id="AppList">

        {this.createApplicationList()}
      </div>); 
  }

  createApplicationList() {
    var guiResult = [];
    for (var key in this.state.AppName) {
      var entry = this.state.AppName[key];
      guiResult.push(
      <Collapsible trigger={entry.AppName + "\t" + "\t"  + entry.Count + " files"} className="AppList" transitionTime ="10"> 
      </Collapsible>);
    };  
    return guiResult;
  }
```

my scss for this component

```
.AppList{
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a886;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

[image: Collapsible tree structure]

Comment: can you add the code to the `Collapsible` component?

Comment: It is not possible to use CSS to determine what the variable will look like based on your code. However, you can apply it to the rendered HTML.
Could you add the code of the output HTML? You can get this from the browser's element inspector.

Comment: he can, the variable will be put in some sort of element and he can style that, also applying direct styling to the rendered html is a bad practice

Comment: @Radu i used this package for collapsible component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapsible

Comment: So use your browser dev tools and find out what HTML structure this eventually renders … then you’ll know which _elements_ to target for formatting.

Comment: thanks. i can see the class now in which i can apply.But one more doubt. I have added the image above and i would like to add css to the .collapsible__trigger is-closed        .Collapsible__trigger is-closed{
  border-bottom:10px solid red;
} but it is not working. any hints??

Comment: on the documentation there is a section called `CSS Class String Props`, I suggest you take a look there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.Collapsible .Collapsible__trigger {
  color: blue;
}
```

`.Collapsible` selects all elements with the `Collapsible` class. `Collapsible_trigger` does the same for the `Collapsible__trigger` class. Together, the rule selects all `.Collapsible__trigger` elements within `.Collapsible` elements, and styles them with blue text.

This is based purely on your provided HTML code. The JavaScript appears to be irrelevant.

`.Collapsible .Collapsible__trigger.is-closed` also works and is more specific. Depends on your use-case.

Comment: @user28 Don't forget to accept the answer (the check button) when someone answers your question.